# problem in pygtk multi-threaded chat application

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, pygtk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Socket Thread and PyGTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453655/socket-thread-and-pygtk)

i want to build a GUI chat application.. I want to create a thread which able to accept the requested connection simultaneously. and show a message box to confirm requested connection to be accepted or rejected. The message box haven't appearing when the application running , it shows when the application close.. I am really getting confused.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

w=gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
ChatSock=PrivateChatWindowContent.ChatSocket(w)
#This the thread i am calling from main
    t=Thread(target=ChatSock.ListenThread)
#t.setDaemon(1)
t.start()
```

This is the class for crating socket and listening on it...

```
class ChatSocket():

def __init__(self,window):
self.window=window
self.sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:        
  self.sock.bind(('',30099))
except ValueError,e:
  print e
self.sock.listen(10)
return

def ListenThread(self):
while 1:
#print "while loop"
(self.new_sock,self.client_addr) = self.sock.accept()
            self.new_sock.settimeout(1)

self.CloseDialog = gtk.MessageDialog(self.window,                                                       gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,                                 gtk.MESSAGE_QUESTION,                                       gtk.BUTTONS_YES_NO,                                     "New chat request from IP: [SomeIP]\nDo you want to accept?")
respons=self.CloseDialog.run()
if respons==gtk.RESPONSE_YES:
    print "connection accepted"
    self.CloseDialog.destroy()
    ChatWindowThread=PrivateChatWindowContent.ChatWindow
            (self.window,[client ip],[client name])

elif respons==gtk.RESPONSE_NO:
    print "connection rejected"
    self.CloseDialog.destroy()
    self.sock.close()
return
```

Comment: It would help if you could create a minimal example of the problem you're having, preferably a single file which other people could easily run and observe it themselves. Along the way towards making this minimal example, there's a good chance you'll solve your problem on your own :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gtk is not thread safe, it is merely "thread aware" (and essentially "thread incapable" in Windows). Only one thread can access a Gtk object at any time.

In your main program, you first need to call gtk.gdk.threads_init() before you call any other gtk functions. Then, in your thread, any time you want to access any gtk objects, you must first call gtk.gdk.threads_enter() and then after you access them, call gtk.gdk.threads_leave().